# Warning on updating flatpak: "runtime is not longer supported"

Tags: gnome, software-updates, flatpak

On updating my *Flatpak* with `flatpak update`, I get following message:

```
Info: org.gnome.Platform//3.36 is end-of-life, with reason:
   The GNOME 3.36 runtime is no longer supported as of February 13, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported platform.
Applications using this runtime:
   org.gimp.GIMP
```

I have tried `flatpak repair` to no avail.

Do you know how I can correct this problem? Should I really contact the developers of GNOME 3.36?
Thanks.

By the way my OS is Linux Ubuntu 16.04. LTS (in case it matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this by running

```
flatpak run --runtime-version=3.38 org.gimp.GIMP
```

To get it fixed properly,

> Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported platform.

means that you should contact the *GIMP* developers, not the GNOME developers. But that’s already been done, see [issue 84 in the GIMP flathub repository](https://github.com/flathub/org.gimp.GIMP/issues/84).

Comment: Thanks, specially for the link a very useful thread. By the way, as the version 40 is already out, they recommend `flatpak run --runtime-version=40 org.gimp.GIMP`. Both work in my case, but I guess that using the last version is advisable.

Comment: Well, “they recommend” is a bit of a stretch, one person mentioned it (or perhaps you’re referring to some other recommendation somewhere else). In such circumstances I tend to favour using the lowest supported version, to minimise the risk of disruption.